# Highchart negative time

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I got a example from internet about highchart date and time toghether.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Time Worked per Day'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
     
        labels: {
     
            formatter: function() {
                return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value/3600000,0);
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Hours'
        },
        tickInterval: 3600000
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    return  Highcharts.dateFormat('%Hh%M',new Date(this.y));
                }
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return  '<b>' + this.series.name +' : </b>' +
                Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y/3600000,2);
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Hours',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [ ["23-05-16", 9000000], ["24-05-16", 7000000],["25-05-16", 9000000], ["26-05-16", 7000000], 
        ["27-05-16", 8000000], ["28-05-16", 9000000], ["29-05-16", 7000000], ["30-05-16", 8000000], ["01-06-16", 8000000], ["02-06-16", 8000000]]
    }]
    
});
```

The problem is when a put negative value, it´s got 23:00, intead of for example show up -01:00, this event because of this Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y/3600000,2) I have to do a if when negative value to do (3600000,2/this.y) intead of (this.y/3600000,2)

https://screenshot.net/9o88nt7

Comment: May be dateFormat is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see any question, regardless, I assume you were after showing negative values as `-x.xx` hours instead of `24 - x.xx` hours. I added an `if` to the datalabel formatter, like this:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function() {
        if (this.y < 0) {
          return Highcharts.dateFormat('-%Hh%M', new Date(Math.abs(this.y)));
        } else {
          return Highcharts.dateFormat('%Hh%M', new Date(this.y));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It now displays negative values as `-x.xx` hours.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/y5ygdx2a/